# Text Committing keyboard shortcut Consistency across Adobe Apps - AE, Premiere, Illustrator & Photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects, shortcuts, adobe-premiere

Different Adobe application uses different ways to commit text (or exit text-editing mode)

Photoshop - Numeric Enter Key & Escape Key

Premiere - Numeric Enter Key & Escape Key

Illustrator - Ctrl + Numeric Enter & Escape Key

After Effects - Numeric Enter Key

Now what happens in worst cases due to habit

**If we learn Numeric Enter key** habitually to exit editing mode, it works for Photoshop, Premiere Pro, After Effects but in Illustrator, cursor comes to the next line.

**If we learn Ctrl + Numeric Enter key** habitually to exit editing mode, it works for Photoshop, Illustrator, Premiere Pro but in After Effects, cursor comes to the next line.

**If we learn Escape Key** habitually to exit editing mode, it works for Photoshop, Illustrator, Premiere Pro but in After Effects, it cancels or reverts the text.

It makes very difficult to work on cross-application, especially if you are working on Illustrator and After Effects simultaneously.

Is there any script or any other way to edit these native keyboard shortcuts to make life easier.

Comment: What OS are you on? On Windows you can use AHK (free) to map a particular key (say Numpad Enter or any other) to call for different ways of committing text depending on application. On Mac there's Keyboard Maestro (paid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows I'd go with [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/). This script will remap <kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd> only for Illustrator:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
#SingleInstance force
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
DetectHiddenText, On

#if WinActive("ahk_exe Illustrator.exe")

NumpadEnter::
Send ^{NumpadEnter}
return
```

This way <kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd> will work for all 4 applications. To use it:

1. Install AHK
2. save this as an `.ahk` file anywhere and run via AHK.
3. Add a shortcut to this file to your Startup menu to run it after every restart.
4. After realising how powerful this is make 40 more scripts to automatize different tasks.
5. After a year of learning scripting rewrite them all to work as modals, using variables and whatnot
6. Get 3 more keyboards only for macros

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. How difficult for Adobe to add this as an option, or even make this consistent across all apps.

Comment: Apparently it's _very_ difficult. There're so many UX things in some apps that miss or mismatch things from other apps...

Comment: @MohdFaizan its not hard just time consuming to go through entire code. It does however make management very jumpy.

Comment: @joojaa Then what's the point of update Adobe releases every year.

Comment: @MohdFaizan there is no point. Adobe does not realease things that i consider an upgrade more than once every 3 years. In fact you are better of not upgrading.

Comment: @MohdFaizan to please shareholders

Answer (score 0):

No, the management layer that does keyboard shorcuts does not actually penetrate all levels of the applications. Since scripts are limited in what they do they can not penetrate more than the applications allow you to do anyways.

There are functions in photoshop that you can only invoke if you use a english keyboard layout for example.

It might be possible (but really dangerous) to make use of something like autohotkey though.

Comment: Why is it really dangerous?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy because autohotkey likes dont know context. So while they can identify application used they are oblivious to the fact that you are using type tools. So if you instruct them to override something X then they override that in all contexts. So they can permanently lock you out of features.  Also they may not be as portable as you think. Anyway on windows alt-tab exits eitger tool gracefully.

Comment: I wonder if that can be very true if you distribute your scripts and if something is undocumented or there're too much features in the script it may cause panic (saw this with premade Photoshop 'enchancers'), but if you do it for yourself and use in a controlled environment..? Like in OP's example he only needs to remap NumEnter for Illustrator

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy it depends on how good your memory is. It creates a layer of impossible for others to deal with. This is especially dangerous if you dont manage this layer. There is generrally a value in being same as what bulk of people are seeing. You can get free help. Now any time you now have a problem you need to account for all customisations in debugging. Now do you use numpad enter for anything else. It is alo a performance hit.

Comment: Yes I know what you're talking about: my employer allows me to do wahtever I want with my PC so I have my keyboard remapped to Mac layout (ctrl, alt and win switched) and have tons of AHK scripts on top of that. If I ever go to work for a place without Admin access to my PC I'm busted. Also IT guys hate me. But that's the price I'm ready to pay :D and I encourage others to follow the same steps into oblivion.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy yes, you can do that. But then thats only for those people who never need things from others. Personally i have trained my brain to be more elastic. I mean for some reason each and every 3D app that i need to support uses different key/mouse combo for screen manipulation. I couldnt even come up with that many keyboard combos.